# Limit at infinity.

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim _{p\to \infty }\left(p\ln \left(e\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)^{1-p}\right)\right)?$$

I was getting $1$ as an answer but answer is $1.5$. 
I solved it like this:-

$$\lim_{p\to \infty} p\ln\left(e\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)^{\left(1-p\right)\frac{p}{p}}\right)\right)$$
$$\lim_{p\to \infty} p\ln\left(e\cdot e^{\frac{1-p}{p}}\right)$$
$$\lim_{p\to \infty} p\ln\left(e^{\frac{1}{p}}\right)$$
$$\lim_{p\to \infty}p\frac{1}{p} = 1$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I do not understand your equation, please try and reformat it.

Comment: Do you mean $\lim _{p\to \infty }\left(p\ln \left(e\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)^{1-p}\right)\right)?$

Comment: Is this what you want? : $$\lim_{p\to \infty} p\cdot\ln\bigl[e\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)^{(1-p)}\bigr]$$ or $$\lim_{p\to \infty} p\cdot\ln\bigl[e^{\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)^{(1-p)}}\bigr]$$ ?

Comment: I tried to edit it but I realise there are '^' signs - to format these, write ^{}, not ^()

Comment: p*(ln(e*((1+1/p)^(1-p)))

Comment: That's right, Itay4.

Comment: Aman, use `@` before writig someone's name to notify, for example @AmanSharma

Comment: You must take the entire limit as a whole

Comment: The limit doesn't tend to infinity, but $p$ does.

Comment: in other words, you can't substitute (1+1/x)^x for e in the middle

Comment: Thanks @SakethMalyala . So shall I use expansion? Or any other approach that you can think of?

Comment: @AmanSharma: In general, I prefer to use explicit big-$O$ and little-$o$ terms to bound the limiting expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: The expression equals

$$p + p(1-p)\ln(1+1/p).$$

Recall $\ln (1+u) = u-u^2/2 + O(u^3)$ as $u\to 0.$

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Got it at once

Answer (score 3):

First observe that

\begin{align}
p \ln \left[ e \left(1+\frac1p\right)^{1-p} \right]
    & = p \left[ 1 + (1-p)\ln \left(1+\frac1p\right) \right] \\
    & = p + (p-p^2) \ln\left(1+\frac1p\right)
\end{align}

Now, recall the Taylor series expansion of $\ln (1+x)$ around $x = 0$:

$$
\ln (1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + o(x^2)
$$

So then we have

\begin{align}
\lim_{p \to \infty} p \ln \left[ e \left(1+\frac1p\right)^{1-p} \right]
    & = \lim_{p \to \infty} p + (p-p^2) \ln\left(1+\frac1p\right) \\
    & = \lim_{p \to \infty} p + (p-p^2) \left[\frac1p-\frac{1}{2p^2} + o\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right)\right] \\
    & = \lim_{p \to \infty} p + 1 - p + \frac12 + o(1) \\
    & = \frac32
\end{align}